# Convert bitcoin value based on exchange rate from JSON API

Tags: beginner, json, f#, unit-conversion, cryptocurrency

I’m learning F# and trying to find a more ‘functional’ way to code a simple program that retrieves the price of BTC and calculates the EUR value of an amount of Bitcoin.

```
open System
open System.Net
open Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

let myBTC = 0.1234567
let client = new WebClient()
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true
let priceInfo = client.DownloadString("https://blockchain.info/ticker")
let jPrice = JObject.Parse priceInfo
let eurPrice = float (jPrice.["EUR"].["buy"] :?> JValue)
let calcWorth = myBTC * eurPrice
printfn "%s" calcWorth.ToString("N")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My take is that there is no harm in adding a few named functions. Also it is probably better to ignore the result of setting a standard .net property.

```
open System
open System.Net
open Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

let downloadPriceInfo () =
    let client = new WebClient()
    client.DownloadString("https://blockchain.info/ticker")

let getPriceOfEuro (price: JObject) = float (price.["EUR"].["buy"] :?> JValue)

let euroToBtc euro = 0.1234567 * euro

let btcOfEuro = 
    downloadPriceInfo () 
    |> JObject.Parse
    |> getPriceOfEuro 
    |> euroToBtc

printfn "%s" (btcOfEuro.ToString("N"))
```

Comment: Some suggestions, which may or may not be useful...

`|> parseJObject` is equivalent to `|> JObject.Parse`.

 `jPrice` might better be named `price` since the type definition is fully specified here. 

`euroPrice` might be better named `euro` since the function is `EuroToBtc`. 

I'm pretty sure `client.UseDefaultCredentials = true` doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: @VoronoiPotato - You make some good points.

Comment: always happy to help :)